# MySQL index misses

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
select count(*) from `foo` where expires_at < now()”
```

since expires_at is indexed, the query hits the index no problem. however the following query:

```
select count(*) from `foo` where expires_at < now() and some_id != 5
```

the index never gets hit.

both expires_at and some_id are indexed.

is my index not properly created?

Comment: Can you provide an execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    foo
WHERE   expires_at < NOW()
```

can be satisfied by the index only, without referring to the table itself. You may see it from the `using index` in the plan.

This query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    foo
WHERE   expires_at < NOW()
        AND some_id <> 5
```

needs to look into the table to find the value of `some_id`.

Since the table lookup is quite an expensive thing, it is more efficient to use the table scan and filter the records.

If you had a composite index on `expires_at, some_id`, the query would probably use the index both for ranging on `expires_at` and filtering on `some_id`.

`SQL Server` even offers a feature known as `included fields` for this. This command

```
CREATE INDEX ix_foo_expires__someid ON foo (expires_at) INCLUDE (some_id)
```

would create an index on `expires_at` which would additionally store `some_id` in the leaf entires (without overhead of sorting).

`MySQL`, unfortunately, does not support it.

Comment: Since both conditions in the where are ranges a composite index would not be beneficial. I would imagine the best field to index would be the one that reduces the number of returned records the quickest, e.g. if there were 100 records where some_id <> 5 and 101 where expires_at < NOW() then the best field to index would be some_id.

Comment: @James: a composite index would be benefitial to use as a covering index.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what's happening is that for the first query, the index can be used to count the rows satisfying the `WHERE` clause. In other words, the query *would* result in a table scan, but happily all the columns involved in the `WHERE` condition are in an index, so the index is scanned instead.

In the second query though, there's no single index that contains all the columns in the `WHERE` clause. So MySQL resorts to a full table scan. In the case of the first query, it was using your index, but not to find the rows to check - in the special case of a `COUNT()` query, it could use the index to count rows. It was doing the equivalent of a table scan, but on the index instead of the table.

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems you have two single-column indices. You can try to create a multi-column index.

For a detailed explanation why this is different than multiple single column indices, see the following:
http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Indexes/When-does-multi-column-index-come-into-use-in-MySQL

2) Do you have a B-tree index on the expires_at column? Since you are doing a range query (<), that might give better performance.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Best of luck!